# Gnome 3 after run has graphic problems

Tags: gnome, 11.10, ati

I have 3d accelarator but gnome still doesn't work
My pc enters gnome desktop bu there i have graphic problems!
Graphic problems with the top taskbar and wherever i click it, my desktop transforms into gnome clasic desktop.
I am using ati radeon 4800 hd and ubuntu 11.10

```
Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       yes
```

Similar report from @user26930 - ATI HD5770 graphics card - gnome-shell is affected but Unity works fine.

[image]

Comment: I have such problem too but, but Unity works fine... Radeon HD5770 - ubuntu 11.10 with proprietary drivers - [screenshot](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/651/screenvcp.png/)

Comment: I have ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5870 Graphics, and when I use gnome-shell, the top bar is bright blue and only half the letters render, the others are torn or blank boxes. Using proprietary drivers. Gnome 3 worked when I used it on Fedora though. Unfortunately I can't provide a screenshot, as when I make a screenshot, only my wallpaper shows, it must be part of the bug.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my ati card (switched to nvidia now) but I didn't have atis newest driver back then...have you tried to go to the ati page and download the newest linux drivers? It's the amd catalyst 11.10 drivers released october 31